# matplotlib surface plot extends past axis limits

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How do I make a nice paraboloid in Matplotlib that looks like

[image]

All I can get is this,

[image]

where the top is not "cut off". I've tried just dropping all values of the `Z` array outside of the radius of the parabola at the top, but that gives very jagged edges.  Can someone help me?

Here is my code:

```
from matplotlib import *
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import math
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = (X**2 + Y**2)

ax.set_zlim(-10, 20)

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,  alpha=0.9, rstride=4, cstride=4, linewidth=0.5, cmap=cm.summer)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

For future reference, I had a thought to parametrize the surface in cylindrical coordinates, and it looks exactly how I want it:

[image]

```
from matplotlib import *
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import math
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

r = T = np.arange(0, 2*pi, 0.01)
r, T = np.meshgrid(r, T)
#Parametrise it
X = r*np.cos(T)
Y = r*np.sin(T)
Z = r**2

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,  alpha=0.9, rstride=10, cstride=10, linewidth=0.5, cmap=cm.summer)

plt.show()
```

I guess it makes sense: when working with a cylindrical object, use cylindrical coordinates!

Comment: Good workaround! Clearly matplotlib still needs to improve  it's 3d clipping, but in the meantime, this type of approach will work for some cases.

Answer (score 2):

*Manual data clipping*

One approach I've seen that works is to *manually clip the data*; e.g. your example would be updated to

```
from matplotlib import *
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import math
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = (X**2 + Y**2)

ax.set_zlim(-10, 20)

for i in range(len(X)):
    for j in range(len(Y)):
        if (Z[j,i] < -10) or (Z[j,i] > 20):
            Z[j,i] = NaN


ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,  alpha=0.9, rstride=4, cstride=4, linewidth=0.5, cmap=cm.summer)

plt.show()
```

**Note**

This can be done concisely for this case using

```
Z[Z>20] = NaN
```

Resulting in

[image]

Comment: Instead of your for loop, I had tried adding the line Z[Z>(20)]=np.nan, which had the same effect, but really, it's not very pretty at the top.

Comment: @KyleMills: Good point - the code I added was actually taken from a more more general case, where any coordinates can be clipped by changing the i and j, though that could probably be condensed down also.

Comment: I get an empty graph, and "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:23: UserWarning: Z contains NaN values. This may result in rendering artifacts." Upgrading matplotlib fixed this.

Comment: @falsePockets odd that you had that issue before upgrading, as I answered this 7 years ago 